# How can I create a conditional that is able to distinguish between two objects that take on the same value?

Tags: r, if-statement, sample

I am trying to create a code where I sample from two objects and then subsequently I run a conditional based on the value that is sampled. My problem is that, among the objects that are sampled, it is possible for them to have the same value. Therefore, although only one of those objects get sampled, my conditional statement seems to run for all of the objects that have the same value... ( I hope this makes sense).

Here is a very simplified reprex of what I am trying to do with my actual model:

```
x1=5

x2=5


 x = sample(c(x1,x2), size=1, replace=TRUE, prob=(c(0.9,0.1)))

 if(x==x1){print("yes")} else{print("hmm")}

 if(x==x2){print("no")} else {print("it worked!")}
```

In my actual model, it is fairly unlikely that the objects take on the same value, but it is possible. So I want to know if there is a way to avoid the problem as above, such that even though the values taken by objects may be the same, a conditional statement is still able to specifically distinguish one particular object over the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What stops you from sampling the object name, then later evaluating it? For example:

```
x1=5
x2=5
x = sample(c("x1","x2"), size=1, replace=TRUE, prob=(c(0.9,0.1)))

consider_x <- function(y){
print(paste0(y," was sampled."))
print(paste0("Its value is ",get(y)))
}

consider_x(x)
[1] "x2 was sampled."
[1] "Its value is 5"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I suppose this would work but would be a bit of a convenience issue if I had to do this and recall the values, so I was just wondering if there was perhaps a quicker way or basic change I could make to the conditional. If it is the only feasible way however... looks like I just have to bite the bullet!